# Value format in Php Remove caracteres

Tags: php

I have this value :

"24,7 km"

i would like to remove "Km" and get only 24,7 as a float number ! someone know how i could do this ? thanks a lot in advance

here my code actualy :

```
Route::get('/test', function () {

    $origin = '155 avenue franklin roosevelt 11000 Carcassonne';

    $destination = '36 avenue André Chenier 11300 Limoux';

    $response = \GoogleMaps::load('directions')
        ->setParam([
            'origin'          => $origin,
            'destination'     => $destination,
            'mode' => 'driving' ,
            'language' => 'fr',

        ])->get();



   $parsed_json = (json_decode($response));


   $distance = $parsed_json->{'routes'}[0]->{'legs'}[0]->{'distance'}->{'text'};

   dd($distance);
```

UPDATE WORKING :

```
  $parsed_json = (json_decode($response));


        $distance = $parsed_json->{'routes'}[0]->{'legs'}[0]->{'distance'}->{'text'};


        $a = $distance;
        $b = str_replace(" km",'',$a);
        $c = str_replace(",",'.',$b);

        dd($c);
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = "24,7 km";
$b = str_replace(" km",'',$a);
$c = str_replace(",",'.',$b);
```